# Dynamically specify height of parent based on the tallest child element?

Tags: html

I am trying to best figure out how to set two columns' a-elements to 100% of the parent element, without specifying this height, but having it chosen based on the taller of the two columns. At the same time, I want to vertically align the a-element within it's column.

Current code:

```
<div class="post-nav group">

                <div class="post-nav-prev">
                    <div class="post-nav-border border-reset-right">
                    <?php previous_post('%', '', 'yes'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="post-nav-next">
                    <div class="post-nav-border">
                    <?php next_post('%', '', 'yes'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.post-nav {

}

.post-nav-prev, .post-nav-next {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}

.post-nav-prev a, .post-nav-next a {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;      
}

.post-nav-prev a {
    padding-left: 25px;
}

.post-nav-next a {
    padding-right: 25px;
}

.post-nav-border {
    border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    height: 100%;
}
```

What I eventually run into as the problem is when the two post titles isn't the same amount of lines. I originally had a specified height, but this isn't optimal for the responsive aspect of the website.

So to clarify: How would I go about having the tallest of '.post-nav-prev a', and '.post-nav-next a' specify a height for .post-nav, so the other of the two a elements also get 100% height. I've seen suggestions for display: table, but I couldn't quite get that to work, as well as keeping the vertical alignment of display: flex.

Any suggestions?

Comment: btw can you add your full code you have no links in your current code

Comment: Hi! Sorry, it's just calling a link to the next and previous post in WordPress. The HTML is literally just <a href="dummy">Dummy</a>, but Tyblitz' solution worked perfectly! :)

Comment: Consider: `display: flex`, `flex-direction: column` and (key component) `flex-grow: 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution (without JS) is indeed to fiddle with the `display` property and set it the container to `table` and children to `table-cell` (you might as well change the actual markup to be a table, the result is the same). With this, vertically aligning becomes easy as hell and the CSS & HTML are much simpler. Here's how:

```css
.post-nav { 
    display: table; 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
}
.post-nav-prev a, .post-nav-next a { 
    display: block; 
    padding: 10px; 
}
.post-nav-prev, .post-nav-next {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-nav group">
    <div class="post-nav-prev"><a href="#">text 1</a></div>
    <div class="post-nav-next">
       <a href="#">text 2 is too long and falls in 2 lines for the example case</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly, thanks! For some reason, I can't wrap my head around tables.

Comment: Flexbox is another simple, non-JS solution that would work.

Answer (score 0):

if youre open to jquery, would something like this work for you?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    adjust();
    function adjust() {
        if ($('.left a').height() > $('.right a').height()) {
            $('.right a').css("min-height", $('.left a').height());
        }
        if ($('.right a').height() > $('.left a').height()) {
            $('.left a').css("min-height", $('.right a').height());
        }
    }
    
    $('.addLeft').click(function() {
        $('.left a').append('<br/>Adding more');
        adjust();
    });
    $('.addRight').click(function() {
        $('.right a').append('<br/>Adding more');
        adjust();
    });
});
```

```css
.left, .right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
a {
    height: 100%;
    display:inline-block; 
}
.left a {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.right a {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
.container {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="addLeft">Add more to Left</a>
<br/>
<a href="#" class="addRight">Add more to Right</a>
<br/><br/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <a href="#">A element </a>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <a href="#">A element<br/>More content here </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but got it to work without any JS. Thought that would be the solution, but tables seems to have done the trick. :)